# Oracle Forms - Display message blocks rest of the code execution or message doesn't show

Tags: message, show, oracleforms

I'm trying to show a message on a form without success.
What I'm doing is: When a new line is clicked, I use the WHEN-NEW-RECORD-INSTANCE to do some verifications and some enabling/disabling on the form and showing up the message. The problem is sometimes it does the enabling/disabling but not the message, then I click another line and it shows the previous message but doesn't do the enabling/disabling...

I've already tried some stuff like:
message('message');
n := Show_alert('message');

with and without SYNCHRONIZE;

I don't think it's the code itself blocking the messages... or I'm missing something...

Does anyone ever had this problem?
Can someone tell me the various options to display messages and their differences?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I managed to fix this using the WHEN-MOUSE-CLICK trigger instead.
I didn't want to use this at first because when I clicked the already selected line it would show the message again but I made some code verification and fixed it.
Someone can close this.
thanks.